# Strapi fails to stratup on AWS ECS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ecs, strapi

I have a strapi image and a postgres image and I deploy both of the to AWS ECS what happens is

1. Postgres runs and is healthy
2. Strapi tries to startup
3. Strapi fails to startup because it tries to delete a column not existing on a relation
4. Strapi is torn down
5. Postgres is torn down too as they are in the same service

My question is why is strapi failing to run his migrations on startup or rather why is it trying to run old migrations that may not exist anymore

any advise ?